# php array (of arrays) to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I've a MySQL database containing GPS coordinates.
This is my partial PHP code to retrieve the coordinates;

```
$sql = "SELECT lat, lon FROM gps_data";
$stmt=$db->query($sql); 
$result=$stmt->fetchAll();
```

Now i need to 'convert' the returned PHP array to an array of arrays in javascript. I've already tried this;

```
var js_var = <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>;
```

But it's not the desired output

Current Output:

```
var js_var = [{"lat":"61.883350","0":"61.883350","lon":"8.551115","1":"8.551115"},{"lat":"61.883380","0":"61.883350","lon":"8.551715","1":"8.551715"}];
```

Desired output:

```
var js_var =
[[61.883350,8.551115],[61.883380,8.551715]];
```

how to achieve this ?

Comment: Print your array then only we will assist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), like so

```js
var js_var = [{"lat":"61.883350","0":"61.883350","lon":"8.551115","1":"8.551115"},{"lat":"61.883380","0":"61.883350","lon":"8.551715","1":"8.551715"}];

var result = js_var.map(function (el) {
  return [el.lat, el.lon];
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$sql = "SELECT lat, lon FROM gps_data";
$stmt=$db->query($sql); 
$result=$stmt->fetchAll();
$final=array();
foreach($result as $row) {
    $final[]=array($row[0],$row[1]);
}
```

And

```
var js_var = <?php echo json_encode($final); ?>;
```

Comment: Now it outputs as OP needs, i have formed new array as per as his needs